# BASH-SHELL SCRIPT: Print part of the text from a file

Tags: html, bash, shell, sh

So i have a text file with part of html code:

```
>>nano wynik.txt
```

with text:

```
1743: < a href="/currencies/lisk/#markets" class="price" data-usd="24.6933" data-btc= "0.00146882"
```

and i want to print only: `24.6933`

I tried the way with the `cut` command but it does not work. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: What is the criteria for a number getting printed? Are you only worried about `data-usd`?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @ThomasSmyth result.txt is only a temporary file which is deleted at the end of the script, its content depends on what data I download from the website although the text pattern is always the same but the data-usd value is different, for example: 12.1594 or 1203.394, so the text length also it's different. I only need the data-usd value that I can capture into a variable or edit the file result.txt so that only this value is there. I hope you understand the message :).

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does the file really have `1743:` at the beginning of the line? So it's not really HTML, it has extra formatting added?

Comment: This is extra formatting added by grep command, i am downloading index.html from https://coinmarketcam.com and the number is just number of line which is added by grep i think ( i am not really into bash).

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for another advice for future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep and [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions):

```
grep -Po '(?<=data-usd=").*?(?=")' file
```

Output:

```
24.6933
```